# How to update dual boot screen?

Tags: dual-boot

I previously had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on dual boot. Now, I have deleted Windows, but I still get the Windows 7 option on the boot screen, (GRUB related?). I want to update it. I want Windows 7 gone from there. Also, both the OSs were on two different HDDs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** If one of the answers below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and that will update grub!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Check in your grub configuration in /etc/grub.d, delete configuration files related to your windows, example there is a windows grub configuration file as 25_custom (Just in case, make a backup copy of that file in case something unexpected happen).

To make sure, just open that files, it might contain a script looks like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root CA5F-CC4E
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root CA5F-CC4E
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root CA5F-CC4E
chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
}
```

Just delete that file, and then run in terminal :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your computer to check if the Windows succesfully gone from the grub menu.

Comment: @AdityaSharma Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! `As you're a reputation 3 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**